# How to store shared files and images for wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file

Hi i have WPF desktop application which is live client side since 2016. Our app stores diff type of files and images to shared folder on sever so every user can access it. Now the thing is there are thousands of files and its increasing day by day.I am not sure how much more space we can allow our app to use on server.

We simply store files in it original form. I was wondering is there any alternative way to store this files and images ? like can i store it in zip and fetch it by extracting ? or can i store it in db (as far as i know if we store in db it will affect performance while fetching and storing)?.

So is there any ideal way to handle this ? I need to utilize minimum space on server.

Comment: If feasible as per your architecture, you can utilize [Azure Cloud storage services](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/azure-blob-storage-vs-file-storage)

Comment: you can use AWS S3 bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the files into as DB will not save storage space, in fact it will increase it overall.

A file with 1000 Bytes of data will remain a file with 1000 Bytes of data even in the DB, but then you will have the overhead of the DB itself including all the indexes etc. so it will actually take up more space as well as being slower to access and require a lot of reengineering of your solution.  (You may be able to compress it in the DB to reduce the space a bit).

Similarly, storing in ZIP format will also have an impact on performance as you need to ZIP it once, but then UnZip it each and every time you access it.  This requires more CPU performance (so you trade disk space for CPU cycles).  This can be more effective and quicker overall however because a smaller file takes less time to read (although the gain is greater with magnetic HDDs than SSDs or NVMe drives).

Depending on the type of file, you may also not save much (or any) space.  e.g.  JPG files are already compressed so you might only save 0.1% if zipping individually (sometimes due to how the files are stored zipping can actually increase the size on disk!), although you might be able to save more space zipping many files together, but this makes your solution more complex if you need to search within a zip file for a single file and extract it.

An alternative to this is to use disk compression.  This allows you to compress the whole disk via your OS.  It has the advantage of using less physical space as well as effectively delegating the effort of compression and decompression to the OS.  So this means that it is totally transparent to your application and requires no reengineering or coding adjustments.

See this post for details on the impact of compression on the system:
https://superuser.com/questions/411720/how-does-ntfs-compression-affect-performance

You can of course try alternatives such as storing on the cloud.  But of course this is not free.

Otherwise, the only other way to save disk space is to reduce the number of files you store on the disk!